# sql update and return duplicate rows on insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id, SourceA_id, SourceB_id, data
```

data may come from either sourceA or sourceB ids. I need to identify if identical data is already present from the other source and then update all rows with the correspoding sourceid. Here is an example:

```
 id, SourceA_id, SourceB_id, data
 1, null, 55, apple
 2, null, 55, banana
 3, null, 77, orange
```

now new information is added

```
SourceA_id, data
33, apple
```

I now want to update the row with id 1 because it matches the new data

```
id, SourceA_id, SourceB_id, data
1, 33, 55, apple
2, null, 55, banana
3, null, 77, orange
```

It should also update all rows that match the SourceB_id of the matching row:

```
id, SourceA_id, SourceB_id, data
1, 33, 55, apple
2, 33, 55, banana
3, null, 77, orange
```

I don't mind if it works in one or two steps.

I know it should use some combination of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and `RETURNING`

Comment: how do you add the new information in? insert or update?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I use INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: seen this? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: @maSTArHiAn Yes, but I think this only works for the inserted row. But I also need to update other rows when there is a duplicate.